# How can I update a probability space after discovering/considering a new event?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a probability space which includes an event space E. I later find out that there are other relevant possibilities than those that are included in E. In general, how should I form a new probability space to reflect these newly-discovered possiblities? What is required to make an update like this?

Comment: What is an example of what you are asking about?

Comment: @Rando McRandom . If my answer was useful please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by event space you mean a $\sigma$-algebra. It is usually denoted by ${\cal F}\,.$ To model a time evolution that reflects the incoming of new events one has an increasing family of $\sigma$-algebras $({\cal F}_t)_{t\ge 0}\,.$ That is
$$
{\cal F}_s\subseteq{\cal F_t}\subseteq{\cal F}\quad\quad\forall s\le t\,.
$$
This increasing family is called *filtration*. The total is a so called filtered probability space $(\Omega,{\cal F},({\cal F}_t)_{t\ge 0},P)\,.$ This is all fairly standard and covered by any text book on stochastic processes. There is also a discrete version of this where time runs only through $\mathbb N\cup\{0\}\,.$